# How to combine the content of two files by matching the data

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have two files in this format:

File1:

```
ID:1
Data:ABC
ID:2
DATA:DEF
ID:5
DATA:XYZ
```

File2:

```
ID:1
Data:GHI
ID:2
Data:JKL
ID:3
Data:MNO
ID:4
Data:OBC
ID:5
Data:XYZ
```

The expected output is:

ID:File1Data:File2Data

```
1:ABC:GHI
2:DEF:JKL
5:XYZ:XYZ
```

The task is to first match the ID and then print their DATA side by side. Is there any command in bash for this. The ID is not sorted, it could appear in any manner. I am new to Scripting, please help me with this.

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, Actually the original file had a lot of other things as well. I've created a script to show necessary things only (ID and DATA) which is required for further operation. Now, I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}FNR==NR{if($0~/^ID/){val=$2;next};a[val]=$2;next} /^ID/{val=$2;next} a[val]{print val,a[val],$2}'  File1  File2
```

Comment: @nibba, Could you please let me know if this solution worked for you?